# NVidia GTX970M removable device and more

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-settings

First of all, here's my PC specs:

- Alienware 15 laptop, 2015 revision
- CPU Intel i7 4710HQ
- GPUs: nVidia GTX 970M, Intel HD 4600
- RAM 16 GB
- O.S. Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit

Here are the problems:

I had to uninstall Windows 8.1 and roll back to Windows 7 for some reasons. Since I've installed Windows 7 (two days ago), I get the error message "The Nvidia Geforce GTX 970M device is not removable and cannot be ejected or unplugged". I've looked upon the interweb and of all solutions I found none worked for me, doing a cleanup with DDU amongst other. To get things better, the nVidia control panel doesn't always open, and when it does it only shows a couple of settings about 3D and PhysX, nothing else, not even with which GPU run games and programs (I need it since this is a dual GPU laptop).

Last but not least, every now and then when opening, let's say, Dark Souls III, it goes all stuttering, as if it's running on the integrated Intel HD 4600.

Doing a research seems that all these problems are unrelated and, again, none of the solutions I've found worked for me. I do run the latest version of GeForce Experience with the latest drivers (381.65) and the latest updates for Windows 7.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It was the GPU driver. I had the latest version, 381.65, I rolled back to 378.92 and now it works again. Let's hope they'll fix it with the next update.